# Javascript debugging in  Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have script debugging enabled in IE .. I have put the debugger keyword in the file and it gets caught too..
The debugger is already attached to the ie process and type is script ..

When ie prompted "Would you like to debug" I pressed yes and choose Visual Studio 2008 (With my project opened) . When Visual Studio opens up, i get an alert, "There is no source code available for the current location.".
When i put a breakpoint, an older version of the file opens.

I think its some problem related to Visual Studio cache.

Any help?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache ?

Comment: YUP!i did everything from clearing browser cache, resetting IIS and restarting VS.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be what you asked for, but my advice would be to dump VS for javascript debugging and to use [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/1843) for this purpose instead. I did so and would not want to go back.

Besides, Firebug can do so many more useful things than just Javascript Debugging, so if you are seious about AJAX developt you really want to install it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions mate. I do use FireBug when I use Firefox.
But I really need to debug on IE!!
:(

Answer (score 0):

Its not VS cache its browser cache.  F5 to get latest js into the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a frustrating issue.  Here's how to address it in VS 2013 (hopefully you have upgraded).

Go into Internet Explorer>Internet Options>Advanced and uncheck Disable Script Debugging(Internet Explorer) and Disable Script Debugging(Other).

Now when you set a breakpoint in Visual Studio and run your solution in debug mode with internet explorer selected, it will hit your breakpoints.  I'm not sure whether there's any possible way to do it for other browsers.